# Combobox not adding defined named range

Tags: excel, combobox, vba

I have two comboboxes set in sheet1. I need to add the list of sheets to combobox one, which works fine. I need to add the first column of sheet2 to combobox two with the first cell as the name (called "Name"). This code worked for my UserForm, with Me instead of Sheet1, but using either doesn't work for me.

I'm getting an "Object doesnt support this property or method" error.

Thanks,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim refSheet As Worksheet
    Set refSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem oSheet.Name

    Next oSheet

    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = refSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With refSheet.Columns(1)
        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 1)).Select
        Selection.CreateNames Top:=True
    End With

    Sheet1.ComboBox2.RowSource = "Name"

End Sub
```

Comment: sometimes, sheet1 is not the same as sheets(1). You can check in project explorer in the vbe. Maybe your writing needs sheets(1).shapes("combobox1") , or oleobject, or whatever....

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the sheet:

```
lastrow = refSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

should be:

```
lastrow = refSheet.Cells(refSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

When you use "With" here:

```
With refSheet.Columns(1)
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 1)).Select
    Selection.CreateNames Top:=True
End With
```

you should actually use it with the dots:

```
With refSheet.Columns(1)
    .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 1)).Select
    Selection.CreateNames Top:=True
End With
```

(Notice the dots prior to range and cells)
Not using dots in the "With" block refers to the ActiveSheet